# Backup mysql database from live server to my local MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I develop a good website on my local computer, lets called Site A. I have packed them and put to live server which host by hosting company.

Now.. I would like to take database from Site A (live server) to my Site A database that I manage on my PC localhost.

Is there any command line work to update my Site A Database (development area) with current data table from Site A on live server?

Comment: Update, or _overwrite_? (Losing your local modifications)

Comment: empty the tables in local pc and import data using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first from remote server in terminal/cmd:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

after that in local machine terminal/cmd:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password] [dbname] < [backupfile.sql]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have access to remote DB, using command line and  fetch the remote database, you can do something like this:

```
cd "mysql_directory"
```

after, do

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h host_ip DATABASE_TO_MIRROR >c:\backup\database.sql
```