# MySQL data import issues

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried just about everything i can think of (and searched plenty of threads here on Stack)

I am using the following:

```
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'user', 'pass');
}catch (PDOException $e){
  exit('Database Error.');
}
$fileName="file.txt";

$query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fileName' INTO TABLE data FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'  LINES     TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  (email, ip, referalurl, date, firstname, lastname);
eof;

$db->query($query);
echo "success";
```

now in my file (yes im aware its a .txt) its formated like below:
email@gmail.com|IP.IP.IP.IP|yourdomain.com|"2013-12-22 12:03:29"|firstname|lastname

any suggestions would be great.. btw the database connection is successful but no data ever gets saved into mysql for some reason..

Comment: Do you want to import the whole database to a .txt file right ?

Comment: i want to import the entire txt file into the database.. the columns are correct as well

Comment: i don't think this is the correct way  for loading data into mysql you need different format !

Comment: what would be your suggestion?

Comment: First you need to dump the data **from** mysql into any file then load the data to mysql. how to do this ? answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278260/backup-mysql-database-from-live-server-to-my-local-mysql/21278491#21278491)

Comment: I am adding data TO the mysql database.. not pulling from the database.

Comment: he is trying to upload data from a txt file to mysql. how can he dump that data from mysql if he hasn't uploaded it in the first place?

Comment: yes but you have to pull **first** then **add** then only you will get the correct format of **SQL**

Comment: anyway. are you using a windows or unix system?

Comment: also check if you're getting any errors when running the query use a `try catch`  block for the query part as well and try to output any errors

Comment: unix system, the file is in the same directory as the php script (so yes its already uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with mysqlimport (bash)

Comment: Or you could've tried pdo::execute() instead of ::query